# how to change twig variable in include

Tags: symfony, twig

I have two twig template :
full_view.html.twig has this

```
{% set price2 = opttov.smoptprice|split('.') %}
...
{{ price2.0|default('E') }}
{{ price2.1|default('00') }}
```

i want to include the `full_view.html.twig` file in `sale.html.twig` and change the value of `price2`, to something like `price2 = opttov.price|split('.')`.
i wrote in sale.html.twig this in for loop

```
{% for tov in item.tovar %} 
{% include 'DevFarmUGDvorBundle:Catalog:_full_view.html.twig' with {'opttov':tov, 'opttov.smoptprice': tov.price} %} 
{% endfor %}
```

doesnt work

Answer (score 3):

You can construct the parameter for the include in this manner:

```
{% for tov in item.tovar %} 
 {% 
  set opttov = {'smoptprice' : tov.price }
 %}

 {% include 'DevFarmUGDvorBundle:Catalog:_full_view.html.twig' 
     with     
    {'opttov':opttov } 
  %} 
{% endfor %}
```

Hope this help